Is there really any positive use of "abet"? If so, when and how did it develop?
I have always thought "abet" implies helping toward something negative, either criminal action:

Some women paid a high price, landing in prison for abetting his life as a fugitive.

or negative result in general:

The tenants are also suing the city of Chicago for abetting this process. (process's impact must be negative)

consistent with the definition from Cambridge online dictionary: "to help or encourage someone to do something wrong or illegal."
But how come there are positive use of "abet" recently:

Whisky abets the smokiness in the slightly sweet sesame sauce. (BostonGlobe.com, 2018)

even the example in Merriam-Webster's meaning #2:

The singer was abetted by a skillful accompanist.

(Examples above are taken from m-w.com.)
Am I wrong that "abet" is always negative?  If it is a recent development, when did it start and why / how?

The near-exclusive association with assisting criminal activities is relatively recent. In 1617 it was fine to write Honouring and rewarding the good,..and generally abetting thee towards the doing of that which thou desirest, and God would haue done. Neutral or positive connotations probably apply to many more recent citations in the full OED. I just copied that one because there's no possible ambiguity or half-heartedness about it.

related: What is the origin of the phrase “aiding and abetting”?

In this context, Whisky abets the smokiness in the slightly sweet sesame sauce it is likely to be poetically playing on the negative connotation from abet, it is like it is bringing something in that shouldn't be there, perhaps it is a subtle flavour that is hidden at first. This is actually used often in flavour profiles not just for subtlety but also outrageousness, like implying that it is so criminal in how it works that it should be illegal.

@ChrisSchaller Thanks, that usage makes a lot of sense, especially if it has gained currency in flavour profiles.

From the sixteenth century onward abet has frequently occurred in the context of descriptions of criminal behavior. For example, from a 1568 translation of "An Edict or Ordonance of the French King Conteining a Prohibition and Interdiction of Al Preaching and Assembling, and Exercise of Any Other Religion, then of the Catholique, the Apostolique, and the Romaine Religion" (1568):

Officers, as wel in matters of Iudgemente, as in the Courtes of our Re∣ceites, which make profession of the newe pretended Religion, shewinge themselues so blinde in their affections, and so litle remembringe their duetie towards vs, that some of them, instede of wel and truly discharging their Offices, haue found the meanes to take vp certaine of our Cities, and to plucke them from our Obedience: Other haue seased vpō our Reuenues, and with the same haue relieued, succoured, and abetted suche as tooke Armes againste vs, to the great hinderance, dommage, and preiudice of our affayres: geaueth vs fayre warning in this time of troubles, renewed yet againe by those whiche make profession of the new pretended Religion, taking Armes againste vs, and doing all actes of hostilitie and enmitie against the Catholiques, our good and loyal subiects, to take aduise, that some good order may be sette therin, for the preseruation of our said good and loyal subiects, who do verely perswade themselues, that they shal neuer obteine any dewe and lawfull administration of Iustice, at the hands of those of the newe pretended Religion.

Nevertheless, there have also, from very early times, been examples of neutral or positive use of abet. For example, from Anonymous,
The Praise of Musicke Wherein Besides the Antiquitie, Dignitie, Delectation, & Vse Thereof in Ciuill Matters, Is Also Declared the Sober and Lawfull Vse of the Same in the Congregation and Church of God (1586):

In whose fauor notwithstanding I will speak thus much, & my speach is
abetted by good authors that both a choice of musicke is to be made, and a moderation therein re∣tained. Minerua as before cast away hir pshawlme 〈 in non-Latin alphabet 〉 for very shame. And amongest vs euery one will not blow a bagpipe, that wil finger the Lute or Virginals. And as in one banquet all viandes, though all very good, please not alike euery mans diet, so in Musick there are sundrie & delectable sorts, which vnlesse they be ordered wt good discretiō wil not sute al times & persons.


The influence of 'abet' as used in a criminal law context
There is nothing inherently negative in the word abet, for which reason it seems essential to examine the context in which it appears before attaching a negative valence to it. Today, I suspect, any prejudicial association of abet with malfeasance or misbehavior is an outgrowth of the word's presence in the legal term of art "aid and abet." Black's Law Dictionary, fourth edition (1968) offers this entry for that term:

AID AND ABET. Help, assist, or facilitate the commission of a crime, promote the accomplishment thereof, help in advancing or bringing it about, or encourage, counsel, or incite as to its commission. [Cross-reference to a 1938 New Mexico decision omitted.]

Implies knowledge. [Cross-reference to a 1931 California decision omitted.]
At common law it consisted in being present at the time and place and doing some act to render aid to the actual perpetrator of a crime, though without taking a direct share in its commission. [Cross-reference to an 1894 Alabama decision omitted.]
It comprehends all assistance rendered by words, acts, encouragement, support, or presence, actual or constructive, to render assistance if necessary. [Cross-references to a 1926 Alabama decision and a 1921 Iowa decision omitted.] But it is not sufficient that there is a mere negative acquiescence not in any way made known to the principal malefactor. [Cross-reference to a 1924 Illinois decision omitted.]


The 1894 citation in the entry above asserts that "aid and abet" had a specific meaning in English common law—and whether that is true or not, there certainly are instances of the word string "aid and abet" going back to the seventeenth century at least. From Thomas Forster, The Lay-Mans Lawyer (1656):

Midd. The Jurors, &c. do present that I. N. late of T. in the County aforesaid Tincker, such a day and year, &c. not having the fear of God before his eyes, but being led by the Instigation of the devill, intending falsely, craftily, deceitfully, and trayterously to deceive and defraud the Keepers of the Liberty of England, &c. and all the people of the Common wealth of England, at M. in the County aforesaid, ten peeces of false money, of false and mixt Mettalls, to the likeness of the Coyn and Money of another Kingdome, called Dollers, not being the proper Coyn of this Kingdome of England, nor the same to be currant within the Common-wealth of England, falsely and trayterously did counterfeit, make, and coyn, contrary to the forme of the Statute in that case made and provided, &c. and that I. S. late of E. in the County aforesaid Taylor, before the Treason aforesaid, in manner aforesaid committed; viz. Such a day and year, &c. did procure, counsell, aid, and abet the said I. N. the Treason aforesaid, in manner and form aforesaid to do and commit, contrary to the form of the Statute in that Case made and provided, and against the Peace, &c.

And from the introduction to a 1695 translation of Pierre LeMoyne, Of the Art Both of Writing & Judging of History with Reflections upon Ancient as Well as Modern Historians, Shewing Through What Defects There Are So Few Good, and That It Is Impossible There Should Be Many So Much as Tolerable (1695):

The Translating this Incomparable Discourse out of French, is not the Effect of any Criminal, Correspondence with the Enemies of the Present Government; nor will the Buying and Reading it make any one Impeachable upon the Statute, seeing the Importing and Exposing this Rich Cargo to Sale, is only to Benefit and Inrich us, and not to Aid and Abet them.

Seventeenth-century English sources are less likely to refer to "aid and abet" as a set term, however, than to include both words in a longer string of similar verbs—such as "aid, counsell, or abet" (from a 1607 translation), "abet, assist, or aid" (from a 1642 collection of military orders), "aid, assist, or abet" (from a 1648 petition), or "abet, procure, counsel, aid, or comfort" (from a 1661 law compendium).
Be that as it may, abet in most of these instances from legal milieus attaches to unlawful action. One exception occurs in An Exact Abridgment in English, of The Commentaries, or Reports of the Learned and Famous Lawyer, Edmond Plowden, an Apprentice of the Common Law (1650):

It is natural to engender, and nourish after engendred, or otherwise the first is without effect; the Father shall have the Custody and Education of his Son, for his natural affection to him, Litl. fol. 25.33. H. 6.55. and Trespass for taking away his Son, Fitz. nat. br. fol. 143. and 3. E. 4.12.* And the Son shall have an Appeal of the death of his Father before others for his earnest intent of revenge, and his reciprocal love. So a Feoffment to the Son, a Suit depending, is not Champerty, 6. E 3. cap. 274. yet within the words of Articuli super Chartas, cap. 2. because by all Laws the Son ought to aid his Father, and so out of the intent of the Statute; and there by Herle, the Son may abet his Mother to bring an appeal of the death of her husband, and shall not answer Damages.

Here, to abet the Mother is no less acceptable than to aid the Father. But Plowden also uses abet in clearly negative circumstances, as here:

If one be present, and abet a Murtherer, he is principall as well as he that kils the man, and shall be indicted although that the Murtherer flies, and be not attainted, because both are principals in the first and same degree. And he which abets, is not onely principall in the second degree, but if one be Indicted as accessary to two, he shall not be arraigned with the abettor, untill he which flies is also attainted, and adjudged, which agreeth with 40. Ass. 25.7. H. 4.29. and 36. b. And if the abettor be found guilty by one Verdict, and the Murtherer by another Verdict, is acquitted; now Judgement shall be respited against the abettor, for the Court will give more credit to the Verdict, which was charged directly upon the principal act, then another which is charged implicitely and oblique.


'Abet' in Johnson's dictionary and after
Samuel Johnson, A Dictionary of the English Language (1755) explicitly notes the often negative sense of abet:

To ABET. v. a. (from betan, Sax. signifying to enkindle or animate.) To push forward another, to support him in his designs by connivance, encouragement, or help. It is generally taken, at least by modern writers, in an ill sense; as may be seen in ABETTER.

That Johnson's reading of the "ill sense" of abet still holds generally true is evident in the treatment of the word in Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms (1984), which bundles it with a group of similarly unsavory cohorts:

incite, instigate, abet, foment are comparable when they mean to spur on to action or to excite into activity. ... Abet tends to lose its original implication of baiting or hounding on and to emphasize its acquired implications of seconding, supporting, and encouraging <unthinkingly, I have laid myself open to the charge of aiding and abetting the seal cutter in obtaining money under false pretenses—Kipling.> <MR. Howells ... seconded him as often as not in these innocuous, infantile ventures, abetting him in the production of ... plays of an abysmal foolishness—Brooks>

Still, outside the long shadow cast by criminal law usage of the term, abet—and even aid and abet—need not be intended or taken in a negative sense. For example, from Barbara Berglund, Making San Francisco American: Cultural Frontiers in the Urban West, 1846-1906 (2007):

The process of transformation from a walking city to an industrial metropolis was aided and abetted by a variety of sources—the Civil War, the transcontinental railroad, the discovery of Nevada's Comstock Lode, technological innovations, and an expanding population—that also spurred growth, progress, and prosperity.

Most of these aiders and abettors in this excerpt seem reasonably positive, at least in their immediate effects, as do the consequences that the author attributes to them ("growth, progress, and prosperity").
Likewise from Robert Schneiders, Big Sky Rivers: The Yellowstone and Upper Missouri (2003):

Bison abetted Indian geography and mobility in so many ways—tepees and bullboats being the most prominent. Yet bison also aided Teton travel by providing what today's blitzkrieg U.S. Army calls "meals, ready to eat."
...
In the early nineteenth century, dogsleds found widespread use on the smooth frozen surface of the Upper Missouri main stem from December through February. Dogsled transportation abetted Indian and Euro-American mobility during the otherwise sluggish winter months. The contraption also furthered the harried character of the region's geography.


Conclusions
The answers to the posted question therefore appear to be (1) yes, there really are positive uses of abet; and (2) such usage is attested at least as early as 1586 and presumably arose from the objectively neutral nonlegal meaning "to push forward or support" that Johnson introduces before clouding it with the objectively negative word connivance. Indeed the first (based on historical usage) definition of abet in Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) seems quite innocent of skullduggery:

abet {ME abetten, fr. AF abeter, fr. a- fr. L ad- [meaning "to" or "toward"] + beter to bait, of Gmc origin; akin to OE baetan to bait} (14c) 1 : to actively second and encourage (as an activity or plan) : FORWARD 2 : to assist or support in the achievement of a purpose <abetted the thief in his getaway>

Indeed, even the Eleventh Collegiate's second meaning is negative only when viewed through the prism of tendentious usage, not by strict definitional meaning.
It's true that abet's etymological origin in a word meaning "to bait" sounds somewhat ominous, but I think that we may be misreading that word, too, in supposing that it necessarily implies a camouflaged hook or the horrific destruction of a chained animal for sport. A less freighted interpretation of abet might focus on its implication of urging on, pressing the case of, or encouraging,
I imagine that over the past five centuries many people have used abet from time to time in a neutral or positive sense, despite the pejorative influence of the centuries-old set phrase from criminal law "aid and abet." Such neutral or positive usage may have grown more common in recent years, but it is by no means novel.
